# Pass data to controller with Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, parameter-passing

I have a little problem with passing some data from my view to my controller.

Please have a look at this code snippet:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'DomainController@detach', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
                @foreach($domains as $domain)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $domain->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $domain->tld }}</td>
                        <td id="hello">
                            @foreach($domain->tags as $tag)
                                {{ $tag->name }},<br>
                            @endforeach
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @foreach($domain->tags as $tag)
                                {!! Form::hidden('tag_id[]', $tag->id) !!}
                                <button name="domain_id" value="{{ $domain->id }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
                                <br>
                            @endforeach
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

In my Controller is a :

```
$input = Input::all();
        return $input;
```

In my code ( in the last  ) is a button. If I press teh button, I'm getting directed to my controller action. I'm returning the die data in my $input variable and it allways shows me the same tag_id. Allways the very last tag_id of this domain. I don't know why and couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
{!! Form::hidden('tag_id[]', $domain->pivot->id) !!}
```

you're missing the [] in input

Comment: this gives me every tag_id. Thats just an array with every tag_id this domain have. I want the tag_id from the button I'm pressing. But laravel just allways gives me the very last tag_id

Comment: then you must open and close the form inside the loop and make that button type submit with no name attribute, sure if you don't want some client side processing and in this case remove the []

Comment: you're right, I've open/close the form inside the foreach loop and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 fields with the same name:

```
{!! Form::hidden('tag_id', $domain->pivot->id) !!}
<button name="tag_id" value="{{ $domain->id }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
```

Comment: well, that was a copy paste mistake. I've updated my question. The problem is still the same. It allways returns me the last tag_id (220). No matter if I'm pressing the button with the tag_id 1 or 5 or 199. The result is allways tag_id 220 ( just for an example )